Are there techniques to improve objective function shape?
Are there common practices to make nonlinear objective functions smoother or easier to minimize? Scaling or something like this: https://arc.aiaa.org/doi/abs/10.2514/3.11001?journalCode=aiaaj?

Linearizing the non-convex part
https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/papers/pdf/cvx_ccv.pdf#page=1&zoom=100,0,0
This gurantee that you would arrive at stationary point (not global)
